# return multiple functions in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart

I want to return various functions as the javascript object.

```
payments(auth_user).create();
payments(auth_user).delete(1);
```

to do this in javascript, look like this:

```
function payments(auth_user) {
    return {
        delete(id) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

But in Dart... How to do it?

Comment: Can you try make a working JavaScript example of what your want to do in Dart?

Answer (score 0):

The Dart way is to create a class that implements `.create` and `.delete`, and have `payments` return an instance of that class.  There are no "anonymous classes" in Dart, as you can pretend in JavaScript.